# Фильтрация списка в Битрикс по свойствам элементов инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

У меня есть элементы инфоблока у которых есть кастомное свойство с кодом VACANCY_TYPE, как вывести все элементы инфоблока у которых VACANCY_TYPE = 1?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news",
    "",
    Array(
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "1",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
    "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
    "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
    "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "14",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1",
    "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array("ID",""),
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("VACANCY_TYPE","",""),
    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "NEWS_COUNT" => "20",
    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
    "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
    "SEF_MODE" => "N",
    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    "SHOW_404" => "N",
    "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
    "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
    "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
    "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
    "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
    "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
    "USE_FILTER" => "N",
    "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
    "USE_RATING" => "N",
    "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
    "USE_RSS" => "N",
    "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
    "USE_SHARE" => "N",
    "VARIABLE_ALIASES" => Array("ELEMENT_ID"=>"ELEMENT_ID","SECTION_ID"=>"SECTION_ID"),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае лучше использовать не комплексный компонент news, а простой news.list.

```
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = ['PROPERTY_VACANCY_TYPE' => 1];

$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "",
    Array(
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
       ...
```

Comment: А, вот почему это не работало на комплексном... На комплексном вообще фильтрации нет никакой?

Comment: На комплексном встроен собственный компонент фильтрации, который сам работает с глобальным фильтром.